# Mongoose Bulk Upsert - No operations specified

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, bulkinsert

I am trying to use mongoose's bulk operations to upsert objects. However, I get the error `Invalid Operation, no operations specified` since when debugging I see that the bulk array of operations is empty.

Any clue why this occurs?

```
const bulk = Transaction.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
transactions.forEach((transaction: any) => {
       const data = this.extractTransactionData(transaction)
       bulk.find({hash: transaction.hash}).upsert().updateOne({$set: data});
});
bulk.execute((err: Error) => {
    // log error
});
```

The transaction is not found by find() since it does not exist yet, but it should be added nevertheless through an upsert.

Also `bulk.insert(data)` does not work.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message (some different code). Following

Comment: @shapiroyaacov My workaround for this was to just check before executing the bulk if there are bulk operations in it like so:
```if (bulk.length !== 0) bulk.execute()```. I think there was just nothing found by the find() method